# Dimension of image and characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

What does the characteristic polynomial tell us about the dimension of the image of a linear transformation of vector spaces (say over $\mathbb{Q}$)?

The particular example I'm looking at considers a linear transformation $f : V \longrightarrow V$ with the characteristic polynomial of $f + I$ (where $I$ is the identity map) equal to $x^p - 1$. There is a paper I'm reading which says that $p - 1$ must divide the dimension of the image if it is nontrivial. The justification given was that the only divisors of the characteristic polynomial of $f + I$ are $x^{p - 1}  + \ldots + 1$ and $x - 1$ (which is clear), but I don't understand why this leads to the conclusion above.

More generally, what are some (classes of) examples of finite groups $G$ acting on finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ such that the invariant subspace $V^G$ spans all of $V$? The case above was $G = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ acting as multiplication by a root of unity.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, actually. The characteristic polynomial in your example is $p(x) = (x-\zeta)^n$. So, its divisors are $(x-\zeta)^k$, $k=1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion! The vector spaces were over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Question is not clear. But apparently $f$ is annihilated by $X^p-1$, in which case it is invertible and it image is the entire space $V$, regardless.

Comment: Also in this case, why is $x-1$ a divisor of $(x-\zeta)^n$?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Edited map which is subject of the question (meant to indicate difference of a map with characteristic polynomial $x^p - 1$ and identity map).